# SQL Count with distinct and matching two different tables

Tags: mysql, count, distinct

I have table1 and table2 and I am trying to count the total of unique matches between them for a particular column in each.

```
select count (distinct phone1) from table1,table2 where table1.phone1=table2.phone2;
```

I think I am pretty close but I keep getting a syntax error.  I am using distinct to get only the unique matches as there are several duplicate matches.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query looks correct, you just need to remove the space between count and the opening bracket, i.e. should be `count(x)` not `count (x)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(phone)
FROM (
    SELECT phone1 AS phone
    FROM table1
    UNION
    SELECT phone2
    FROM table2
) a
```

UNION will eliminate the duplicate results and then you just COUNT the resulting records.

From the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html):

> UNION is used to combine the result from multiple SELECT statements
> into a single result set.
>
> The default behavior for UNION is that duplicate rows are removed from
> the result.

### EDIT

I misunderstood the question. I thought you wanted to count all the different numbers.

For that, your query was pretty much ok, appart from the space in between COUNT and (

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I ran that and received "ERROR 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias.

Comment: Now received same error but function database.count does not exist.

Comment: The OP wanted the count of matching phone #'s.  This is the count of all phone numbers.

Comment: I'm good now guys.  Thanks for the help though!  I was just missing a space as trf indicated.

Comment: @AgRizzo. You are right. I misunderstood the question. I thought he wanted all the distinct numbers.